# @media css doesn't work properly

Tags: css

I don't know why but the last "`and (min-width:1280px)`" makes the query not work, if I delete the last "**and**", the query works well:

```
@media (max-width:1280px) and (max-height: 800px) and (min-height:600px) and (min-width:1280px) {
```

I can only put 2 "and"? Or what is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: your width must be exactly 1280px according that. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: max-width:1280px vs min-width:1280px

Comment: Oh, the problem is that I have an app that sets the window resolution to 1280px but probably this won't be exactly 1280px so the query was false...

Comment: Thank all of you. The problem is solved! ;)